# Difference between flex-grow and flex-shrink

Tags: css, flexbox

What is the difference between this two styles:

```
.style1 {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.style2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

If I'm setting the flex-grow to 1, it means that the element can't shrink, and vice-versa, right?

Thank you.

Comment: What? This isn't the same question! @LGSon --"

Comment: Added a second link and updated the first

Comment: Also, the question doesn't need to be the same, it is if an answer can answer both questions.

Comment: Simply put, `flex-grow` tells if to grow or not, where `flex-grow: 0` mean don't grow, and `flex-shrink` tells if to shrink or not, where `flex-shrink: 0`  mean don't shrink.

Answer (score -1):

setting ‘flex-grow: 1’ is default value which will allow an element to increase width evenly.

Setting ‘flex-shrink: 0 ‘ means that element width can be reduced if other siblings have greater width.

Good read on: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/